# Is it Python's interpreter fault that I received a segfault?

Tags: python, segmentation-fault

Can I assume it's Python's bug that I got segfault on condition that:

1. I'm not using any external library
2. I'm barely using any internal library (just sys to increase recursion depth limit and typing for typing :P
3. I didn't observe increased RAM usage that could justify lack of memory and therefore segfault
4. My code is recursive and it doesn't do any advanced memory manipulation (through ctypes or whatever)

I think I don't do anything advanced in my code, and I if these conditions are met, then if I do something wrong I would expect python to raise an exception rather than exit program unexpectedly with exit code != 0, am I right? What do you think, is posting issue on Python's bugtracker justified in that case? :P

```py
import typing
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)
 
 
class RuleDb:
    _rules: typing.Dict[int, str] = None
 
    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        if not cls._rules:
            cls._rules = {}
 
            rules = open('input', 'r').read().split('\n\n')[0].strip().split('\n')
            for rule in rules:
                number, rule = rule.split(':')
                number = int(number)
                rule = rule.strip()
                cls._rules[number] = rule
 
    @classmethod
    def get_by_id(cls, id: int):
        return cls._rules[id]
 
    @classmethod
    def last_index(cls):
        return max(cls._rules.keys())
 
 
def unroll(rules: RuleDb, rule_string: str):
    unrolled = ''
    rule_string = rule_string.replace('"','')
    if len(rule_string) == 1:
        if rule_string.isalpha():
            return rule_string
        elif rule_string.isnumeric():
            return unroll(rules, rules.get_by_id(int(rule_string.strip('"'))))
 
    if rule_string.count('|'):
        unrolled = unrolled + '('
        left, right = rule_string.split('|')
        left, right = left.strip(), right.strip()
 
        for symbol in left.split():
            unrolled += unroll(rules, symbol)
 
        unrolled += '|'
        for symbol in right.split():
            unrolled += unroll(rules, symbol)
        unrolled += ')'
    elif not rule_string.count('|'):
        for symbol in rule_string.split():
            unrolled += unroll(rules, symbol)
 
    return unrolled
 
 
rules_db = RuleDb()
rules_db.load()
print(
    unroll(rules_db, rules_db.get_by_id(0))
)
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow we can not accept links to code. Put the *relevant* code to demonstrate the problem into the question itself.

Comment: Ok, edited, if that's so.

Comment: Short answer: Probably not. Long answer: I would doubt that python with at least 8 million users (https://slashdata-website-cms.s3.amazonaws.com/sample_reports/ZAamt00SbUZKwB9j.pdf) has some flaw in it that only you did observe. Usually it is your code that has a bug.

Comment: No, it's *your fault* because you did `sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)`. There's a **reason** that there's a limit on the stack: to avoid segfaults and stack overflows.

Answer (score 3):

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)
```

This is likely your fault, not Python interpreter's.

From Python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit:

> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent. A user may need to
> set the limit higher when they have a program that requires deep
> recursion and a platform that supports a higher limit. This should be
> done with care, because **a too-high limit can lead to a crash.**

Comment: I don't see any link to the recursion limit in the question.

Comment: The question has been edited. https://pastebin.com/kE0aaYWb

Comment: Yes, sorry, I see there are some special rules when posting link to pastebin so I had some problems with it.
@pavi2410 thanks :)